# What tools can I use for a Basic C++ Interface on Raspberry Pi running Rasbian

Tags: raspbian, gui, c++

I am designing a system using a Raspberry Pi (Model B - 512mb) that depends on OpenCV libraries for Haar-like feature detection, and fswebcam/gpio/libgphoto2. I need more speed than Python can offer.

My interface requires only text of different sizes and colours and rectangles. The image below shows a very rough paint mockup of the interface required.

[image]

I was able to produce the interface in half an hour using the PyGame engine, which runs at sufficient CPU requirements. I can also run the application from the terminal before `startx`, which runs great, with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key set to exit the application.

I am not too keen to have the standard menu or minimise and exit controls that normal applications have, because this will run on a 5" display with no mouse.

I am looking for a solution like this that I can do with C++, or perhaps a good tutorial on a way to bridge python with C++. Will GTK suit my needs for this.

When using GTK, there are the following packages:

```
libgtk2.0-0        : GTK+ graphical user interface library
libgtk2.0-0-dbg    : GTK+ libraries and debugging symbols
libgtk2.0-0-udeb   : GTK+ graphical user interface library - minimal runtime
libgtk2.0-bin      : programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
libgtk2.0-common   : common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
libgtk2.0-dev      : development files for the GTK+ library
libgtk2.0-doc      : documentation for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
```

Which of these do I need to install to use GTK for this purpose, I would like to keep things as lightweight as possible? Is there another similar engine I can use for C++ like PyGame that may be better than GTK?

**Note:** This is a refined (yet related) post to the one I made on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002103/simple-c-gui-design), which got no replies.

Comment: With such a simple interface, is it really worth even using a GUI?  Unless you plan to dramatically improve upon the design and features of this GUI program, I would look into a command line interface.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want.  Personally, I'm not a fan of GTK, but it is a viable option.  Another would be [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) (pronounced cute).  Personally, I prefer the look of it, it is truly cross-platform, and has a really nice designer suite and a [python library](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt).

Have you considered using a webpage as your application's interface?  Python is capable of creating little mini web-servers so you wouldn't even really need Apache for something as simple as you described.  If python is doing some of the legwork with your application anyway, it may be a fairly easy system.

As far as interfacing Python and C++ goes.  I've never really found a better resource than it's own [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/index.html).  It is a fairly advanced processes, so just be forewarned (I don't know your skill level).

Answer (score 1):

Pygame is built on SDL, which encapsulates openGL.  This presumably works well on the pi since it has hardware support for OGL (more specifically, openGL-ES, which you should take note of, but I will not refer to the distinction any further).  Generally in a linux context, SDL runs inside of the Xorg server, however, it can be run using [the framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer). You imply that you have run pygame without X, so perhaps it is already set up for this.

GTK+ and Qt can also, apparently, be run on the framebuffer.  Seeing as how you don't really need GL level graphics, they *may* be a better choice.  OTOH, SDL will may allow you to customize the interface more.

Having not worked with the framebuffer, I can't say if it is significantly harder than just using X.  Since SDL, GTK+, Qt, and so on are high level layers, most of the work should be exactly the same either way, and I'd approach this by doing the development in X and then figure out how to get it onto the framebuffer later.

There is a good chance the difference won't really matter anyway -- the X server *sans desktop environment* is a pretty lightweight thing. To run it without a DE, you need to create a `~/.Xclients`, eg:

```
#!/bin/sh

midori
```

Now `startx` will present just a web browser and a mouse pointer: no extra workspaces, no taskbars, no menus, no other windows or options, no nothing.  If you think your app is fine that way, GTK+ is probably a good choice.  You can also create windows (as bare rectangles, etc) via Xlib directly, although this is not nearly as well documented as using a widget library like Qt or GTK+.

On linux, the native SDL, OGL, and GTK+ libraries have a C interface, but there are C++ wrappers, at least for GTK+: **gtkmm**; `apt-cache search gtkmm` will show you those.  Presuming you want version 3, `libgtkmm-3.0-dev` should pull in all the packages you need to get going (except maybe gcc itself).

If you want to use SDL, the key package should be `libsdl1.2-dev`.  Again, the interface is C, but will not pose any problems in a C++ context.

Qt is fundamentally a C++ API.